# Scala: How to avoid using the existential type

Tags: scala, existential-type

Suppose I have a trait defined like

```
trait SomeTrait[A] {
  def doSomething(): Seq[A]
}
```

and multiple classes that extend this trait as follows.

```
class SomeClass extends SomeTrait[SomeType] {

  def doSomething(): Seq[SomeType] = {
    :
  }

}
```

Now in another class, I want to store the collection of instances of the classes extending the trait.

```
class AnotherClass {
 pirvate val someClassInstances = mutable.Buffer[SomeTrait[_]]()
 def addSomeClass[A](sc: SomeTrait[A]): Unit = {
   this.someClassInstances += sc
 }
}
```

How can I avoid using the existential type here?

Comment: why you want to avoid using existential type here?

Comment: you can change `SomeTrait[A]` to `SomeTrait[+A]` and use `Any` instead

Comment: I thought that the existential type should be avoided whenever possible. I was not sure whether avoiding it in my case was possible that is why I posted here.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko Do you think it is natural to use `_` or  Any` in my case?

Comment: "I thought that the existential type should be avoided whenever possible." No. This is a perfectly good use for one.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I guess I have misunderstood what I read in some article on the Internet. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: Am not sure about this, but can you use a type alias: type M = SomeTrait[_]  ?

Comment: This is a good article re existential types: https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/02/26/rawtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Does the following meet your needs:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

trait SomeTrait[A] {
  def doSomething(): Seq[A]
}

class SomeClass extends SomeTrait[Int] {
  def doSomething(): Seq[Int] = ???
}

class AnotherClass {
  private val someClassInstances = mutable.Buffer[SomeTrait[_]]()
  def addSomeClass(sc: SomeTrait[_]): Unit = {
    this.someClassInstances += sc
  }
}
```

?